# Fragment is not support in my project

Tags: android

### my android studio project is not support fragment class in old project.but new project is will be supported.the app run time android.view.InflateException Exception displayed.how to created fragment in my project?give me any solution.

```
09-12 10:26:31.066    7892-7892/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sentientit.theiWedplanner, PID: 7892
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sentientit.theiWedplanner/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:341)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1948)
            at com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage.onCreate(Frontpage.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2323)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4841)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:341)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1948)
            at com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage.onCreate(Frontpage.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2323)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

my fragment java class

```
public class Fragadmob extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragadmob, container,   false);

        //Admob        
         RelativeLayout gonad=(RelativeLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.adview153613);
         ImageView addviewimage=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.image123);
         ImageView inap=(ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.addviewimage1);

         //   AdView adView = new AdView(getActivity());
           AdView adView = (AdView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
          AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
          adView.loadAd(adRequest);
         addviewimage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent viewIntent =
                          new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW",
                            Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=SentientIT+America,+LLC"));
                          startActivity(viewIntent);

            }

         });
         inap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),Inapp.class);
                     startActivity(intent);         

                }

             });

          if(addviewimage.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) 
            {            
             addviewimage.getLayoutParams().height = 30;                    
                // code to do for Portrait Mode
            } 
          SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
            boolean isPurchase = preferences.getBoolean("isPurchase",false);
  if(isPurchase){

       gonad.setVisibility(View.GONE); //work 
  }
        return rootView;
    }


}
```

fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/adview153613"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/aagr_background2" >

    <ImageView        
              android:id="@+id/image123"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp"                    
              android:src="@drawable/adview1536132" />        

      <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
       ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
         />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/addviewimage1"
          android:layout_width="@dimen/fwh"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/fwh"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
          android:src="@drawable/close" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

this is my mainactivity xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
   <fragment
        android:id="@+id/adview153613"
        android:name="com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       tools:layout="@layout/fragadmob" />

         <RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/fron"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView2"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="50px"
                 android:background="#003399"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:text="iWedPlanner"
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:typeface="serif" />

             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/cl"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="600dp"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                 android:src="@drawable/ilogo" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView1"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                 android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:text="Welcome to iWedPlanner"
                 android:textColor="#FF9933"
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                 android:textStyle="italic"
                 android:typeface="serif" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView3"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cl"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:text="Your Guide to fun and flawless wedding planning"
                 android:textColor="#FFFF0000"
                 android:textStyle="italic"
                 android:typeface="serif" />

             <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/click"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/cl"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                 android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                 android:background="#FFFFFF"
                 android:src="@drawable/ib" />

         </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:id="@+id/adview1536134"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/aagr_background2" >

    <ImageView        
              android:id="@+id/image123"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="50dp"                    
              android:src="@drawable/adview1536132" />        

      <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
       android:id="@+id/adView"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
       ads:adUnitId="____________________"
         />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/addviewimage1"
          android:layout_width="@dimen/fwh"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/fwh"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
          android:src="@drawable/close" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is your code ? You just posting the error log.. Without code nobody can help you or identify your problem

Comment: Are you using MapFragment??

Comment: no.i am using Fragment

Comment: Your Xml may have some problem.Posting your xml.

Comment: my xml file is already posted.

Comment: com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob is in different package??

Comment: no, its a same package

Comment: Fragadmob has an empty constructor? Its mentioned in the error.

Comment: but in this fragment is support in lollipop device.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with Android Versions.  The device that you are using has lower version of Android and You are trying to you Fragment instead of support Fragments

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity and
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

instead of

```
import android.app.FragmentActivity and
import android.app.Fragment
```

Try adding the fragment in class,

```
  Fragment hello = new Fragadmob();
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,hello);
  fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: import android.app.FragmentActivity its not supporting it ask me to download ajar from the web.What can i do now?

Comment: yeah.. You need support lib for it.. download and add to your project.

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0' this lib used

Comment: Yeah.. Is it compiling now??

Comment: Error even after importing support classes?

Comment: i created new fragment class is dos not worked.same error will be displayed

Comment: If its running in lollipop and not in other devices, then its version issue only.. you have to use support lib properly

Comment: by removing fragment from main activity the app is will be run in all device.so i thing the fragment is error..how to solve this error

Comment: where should i place it??in fragment class or in main activity ??

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar",

Make sure your Fragadmob under the package com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.

Comment: yes.in this package present in  com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the package. You have assigned same id `adview153613` for `RelativeLayout` in `Fragment` and `Fragment` in your `activity_xml`. 
If you are using same `id` for two view in same screen, the conflict may appear.

> Please follow the naming conventions.

You can use same id for multiple view but not while inflating the same view on a same screen. That is the reason why it is throwing an error.
Just give a try and let me know

Comment: how can i solve it In which place i should change the id

Comment: Did u changed the name of the id I stated

Comment: I dont know the exact place

Comment: @parthibanR Please read the answer carefully. Change the name of id that you have used for Fragment tag in your activity xml.

Comment: yes i have changed that id.Now its running process going on

Comment: still its running  my project having more classes it takes more time for running.Once it get finished i will inform u @AkshayMukadam thank you fr being with me and i have posted my xml file above  after changing the id make a look on it