# fragment cannot initialize in my project

Tags: android

The fragment is can not initialize in my project.the new empty fragment is created.but in this fragment not worked.display sum errors.but new project include the the same fragment class is worked.how to solved in this issue.give me solution.

```
09-19 15:10:42.396  25251-25251/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sentientit.theiWedplanner, PID: 25251
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sentientit.theiWedplanner/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:341)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1948)
            at com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage.onCreate(Frontpage.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2323)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4841)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:341)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1948)
            at com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage.onCreate(Frontpage.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2323)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Fragadmob" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.sentientit.theiWedplanner-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4841)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:341)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1948)
            at com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.Frontpage.onCreate(Frontpage.java:41)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2323)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2411)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

main java class

```
public class Frontpage extends FragmentActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
      public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
       // The rest of your onStart() code.

        // //  EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStart(this);  // Add this method.

      }

      @Override
      public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        // The rest of your onStop() code.

        // EasyTracker.getInstance(this).activityStop(this);  // Add this method.
      }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(this, "68640bea");
        //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.front);
}
}
```

main xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.aaaFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/aaa_fra" />

         <RelativeLayout
             android:id="@+id/fron"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView2"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="50px"
                 android:background="#003399"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:text="iWedPlanner"
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                 android:textStyle="bold"
                 android:typeface="serif" />

             <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/cl"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="600dp"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                 android:src="@drawable/ilogo" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView1"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                 android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:text="Welcome to iWedPlanner"
                 android:textColor="#FF9933"
                 android:textSize="20sp"
                 android:textStyle="italic"
                 android:typeface="serif" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView3"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cl"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:gravity="center"
                 android:text="Your Guide to fun and flawless wedding planning"
                 android:textColor="#FFFF0000"
                 android:textStyle="italic"
                 android:typeface="serif" />

             <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/click"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/cl"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                 android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                 android:background="#FFFFFF"
                 android:src="@drawable/ib" />

         </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

fragment java class

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class aaaFragment extends Fragment {

    public aaaFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.aaa_fra, container, false);
    }
}
```

fragment xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.sentientit.theiWedplanner.aaaFragment">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you please post code so that we can able to guide you based on your mistake

Comment: where did you called the fragment?

Comment: Same error log with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558652/fragment-is-not-support-in-my-project ? Have you resolved the issue there?

Comment: the fragment is used in Admob function.but the fragment will not support

Comment: no still having the same issue.. :-(